# Декорированные аргументы функции в Python

Tags: python, функции

Видел неоднократно такие функции, где передаются аргументы и своего рода указатель.

Для примера: `add('Иван', 15, table)`

Иван — строковый тип данных, 15 — целочисленный тип данных, но есть еще и аргумент **`table`**, который выполняет функцию некого указателя, или ключа.

Как правильно называется этот параметр? Где можно прочитать про данный функционал?

Comment: похоже `table` - это просто название переменной

Comment: @Grundy, нет это типа True или False. Например add('Иван', 15) мы добавим имя Иван и 15, если добавляем log в функцию add('Иван', 15, log), то например программа сделает еще и лог данной функции.

Comment: Покажи определение функции `add`

Comment: @Grundy, это просто вымышленная функция
Ну вот на примере Tkinter `widget.bind("z", callback)` (событие нажатия клавиш на клавиатуре), callback вызывается каждый раз, когда будет нажата клавиша "z". Я прошу прощения если я чего-то не понимаю или не правильно выражаюсь.

Comment: Добавь конкретный пример в вопрос

Comment: [Функция высшего порядка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак не называется, это просто переменная. Другое дело, что переменная может быть абсолютно любым объктом, а с некоторыми объектами можно делать довольно интересные вещи.

Например, в питоне функция - это тоже объект. Поэтому мы можем передать функцию в качестве аргумента функции:

```
def foo(a):
  print('Функция foo сработала с аргументом ' + str(a))

def bar(number, function):
  function(number)

bar(7, foo)

# Напечатает: Функция foo сработала с аргументом 7
```

Или можно передать в качестве аргумента любой изменяемый объект, функция что-то сделает с этим объектом, и изменившеся состояние будет у этого объекта и вне функции. Возможно, это именно то, что вы подразумеваете под словами "некий указатель":

```
def egg(spam):
  # Изменяю переданный объект
  spam.append('cheese')

my_list = []

egg(my_list)

print(my_list)

# Напечатает: ['cheese']
```

А в указанном вами примере с ткинтером, метод bind, похоже, просто сохраняет в какой-то словарь пару `(буква, функция)`, а каждый раз, когда виджит фиксирует нажатие клавиши, он проверяет, есть ли такая буква в его словаре, и если есть, вызывает соответствующую функцию.

Во всём этом нет никакого особенного функционала. Это просто следствие того, что в питоне абсолютно всё является объектом, которые можно передавать в качестве аргумента. И функции - объекты, и классы - объекты, и всё остальное - тоже объекты.